# SQL where clause performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a table that assigns an user id and a product id to some data (models 2 one to many relationships). I will make a lot of queries like

```
select * from table where userid = x;
```

The first thing that I am interested is how big should the table get before the query starts to be observable (let's say it takes more than 1 second).

Also, how this can be optimised?

I know that this might depend on the implementation. I will use mysql for this specific project, but I am interested in more general answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the horse power of your machine.  The make that query more efficient, create an index with "userid"

Answer (score 0):

> how big should the table get before the query starts to be observable (let's say it takes more than 1 second)

There are too many factors to deterministically measure run time.  CPU speed, memory, I/O speed, etc. are just some of the external factors.

> how this can be optimized?

That's more staightforward.  If there is an index on `userid` then the query will likely to an *index seek* which is about as fast as you can get as far as *finding* the record.  If the `userid` is a *clustered index* then it will be faster because it won't have to use the position from the index to find the record in data pages - the data is physically organized as part of the index.

Answer (score 0):

> let's say it takes more than 1 second

With an index on `userid`, Mysql will manage to find the correct row in (worst case) `Oh (log n)`. In "seconds" it now depends on the performance of your machine.

It is impossible to give you an exact number, without considering how long one *operation* takes.

As an Example: Assuming you have a database with 4 records. This requires 2 operations worst case. Any time, you double your data, one more operation is required.

for example:

```
# records | # operations to find entry in worst case
  2           1
  4           2
  8           3
  16          4
  ...
  4096        12
  ...
  ~1 B        30
  ~2 B        31
```

So, with a huge amount of records - time almost remains constant. For 1 Billion records, you would need to perform ~ 30 operations.

And like that it continues: 2 Billion records, 31 operations.

so, let's say your query executes in `0.001` second for 4096 entries (12 ops)
it would take arround (`0.001 / 12 * 30`) `0.0025` seconds for 1 Billion records.

Heavy Sidenode: this is *just* considering the runtime complexity of the binary search, but it shows how the complexity would *scale*.

In a nutshell: Your database would be unimpressed by a *single* query on an indexed value. However, if you run a heavy amount of those queries at the same time, time increases ofc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer is based on the complexity of binary search. However, binary search requires that data is sorted (in this case, after user_id). What if I search for product_id? Does sql use some complicated data structures that allow it to perform binary search on any column?

Comment: @Paul92 that's what mysql indexes are for: Whenever you create an index on a certain column, mysql will maintain a sorted list of *that* column, in order to perform binary searches on it. This is why indexes are fast for searching, but slowing inserts down (then the index has to be updated as well).